# Camera Failed to capture still image with request CAMMutableStillImageCaptureRequest

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, overlay

I use the `UIImagepickercontroller` to take images. Its a custom overlay camera.

I use not the image preview.

I take multiple images and save them in a folder. And I think this is the problem.

If I multiple click on the `"takePicture"` button the whole time
I get this output:

```
[Camera] Failed to capture still image with request <CAMMutableStillImageCaptureRequest burstIdentifier:(null) irisIdentifier(null)> (Error Domain=CAMCaptureControllerErrorDomain Code=-22100 "(null)")
```

Sometimes the app crashes. with this error:

```
[Camera] Attempting to generate BGRA thumbnail data of format 5003 with an invalid surface.
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you used any type of "mediaTypes" in image picker.

if you want to take picture from image picker you no need to set "mediaTypes" in image picker, only user "takePicture" method.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was solved after deleting the app once from the device. I had given the permission for using the camera with the live app and the development app did not demand the permission again. With the complete new installation everything works fine.